# Trouble finding/fixing a NullReferenceException, Windows WCF Service Application

Tags: c#, wcf, debugging, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

First of all, this is my first post so apologies in advance if I'm neglecting to include anything. Please let me know if I'm doing it wrong.

I'm developing a Windows 8 Store app and having it consume a WCF service I've made. My end goal is to pull data from an SQL database and present in graphs.

For the sake of isolating the problem, I dropped the sql portion (even though the problem exists regardless) and created a table from scratch, so my Service class is as follows:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{

    public DataSet querySql()
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add();

            dt.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "Test1");
            return ds;
        }
```

From there I attempt to retrieve this data within the windows application like so:

```
private async void LoadChartContents()
    {

        // create proxy instance
        DatabaseService.Service1Client serviceClient = new DatabaseService.Service1Client();

        // async call to wcf method to get returned data          
        DatabaseService.querySqlResponse ds = await serviceClient.querySqlAsync();
```

There is more to that method, but it was breaking at the last line of the block I posted.
Here is where I also ran into problems with the debugger. I tried changing a few settings in hopes of getting closer to the problem, but I'm not sure if it helped. When it breaks now I get taken to App.g.i.cs where global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() is highlighted in

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

The exception in the Locals tab says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
InnerException is null, Source is System.ServiceModel, and StackTrace is a hefty:

http://pastebin.com/QiXCPci1

What that looks like is a null pointer exception, but I'm having trouble figuring out where it's occurring

I have a feeling that the ds in `DatabaseService.querySqlResponse ds = await serviceClient.querySqlAsync();` is null because that was where it was breaking earlier, but I can't be sure and I can't see why that would be null.

Again, sorry if this isn't clear. Please let me know what other information should be included. Thank you in advance for your help :)

EDIT:
Thanks to gunr2171, I was able to pinpoint the error further. Now it says:

> Fatal Exception'1' occurred.
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException'1' occurred in mscorlib.dll

EDIT: 
Alas, I am still lost, but I will update this post if I make any progress.

Comment: You have a try/catch, so you probably can't see the exact line the exception is occurring on. Hit `Ctrl + Alt + E` to bring up the Exceptions Options, then check `Thrown` under `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`. This _might_ help you track down the exception.

Comment: Ok I did that and it did help. Now it pinpoints the line that I suspected with a more detailed message. Thank you! However, I'm still not sure how to fix it. it says:
FataException1 occurred. A first change exception of type System.Servicemodel.FaultException'1' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Edit your post to include the new information you found. The edit button is just below the post's tags.

Comment: Gotcha, learning protocol. I edited it

Comment: Where is the WCF service? Is it on localhost or the LAN? If on localhost you may have to enable loopback access for your app. If on the LAN you have to declare the private network capability in the app manifest.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The service is on localhost. I haven't heard of loopback but i'm looking it up [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx). Is this what you mean? Anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: @user3653246 when sending a response to me, please @reply my name (use `@chue` in your text).  Otherwise I am not notified of your message. In reference to loopback, you are correct about the link. Please note the text in the link *"Loopback is permitted only for development purposes"*.

Comment: @chuex Now I know :) thanks. I don't intend to release the app to the windows store, but I would like to install it on multiple devices. Do you know if that is possible/allowed?

Comment: I believe it is only possible for development purposes; one exception is you can do it if you buy some kind of "enterprise" license but that is very expensive. I believe you can google "side loading" to find out more.

Comment: If you find the solution to your original question above, please add the solution as an answer below. That way others with the same problem will know what to do.